# When I use the GTK library, the show window and hidden window are easy to crash

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtk2

When I use the GTK library, the show and hidden window are easy to crash, such as the following

```
gtk_widget_hide(data->draw_window);
sleep(2);
gtk_widget_show(data->draw_window);
gdk_window_raise(gtk_widget_get_window(data->draw_window));
```

My program needs to show or hide a window frequently. Sometimes switching between these two states four times will crash. If I'm lucky, it will crash 10 times

Comment: Are you on the UI Thread?

Comment: emmm,i made the thread that control the window hide or show.

Comment: Try to use [g_timeout_add_seconds](https://www.geany.org/manual/gtk/glib/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds): use _GSourceFunc function_ so you can every the seconds you wanted show/hide the toplevel.